# OpenCV / How to handle CvMat arrays in java

Tags: arrays, opencv, javacv

How to read/write from/to an array of CvMat (Java)?
In the code below I put a CvMat to the array. But reading seems not to get the CvMat.

```
import com.googlecode.javacpp.Pointer;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.CV_IS_MAT;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.CvMat;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.IPL_DEPTH_32F;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.IplImage;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.cvSize;

public class Ask {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Ask().go();
    }

    private void go() {
        CvMat matQ = new opencv_core.CvMat(3); //array of 3 CvMat
        IplImage i = opencv_core.cvCreateImage(cvSize(10, 10), IPL_DEPTH_32F, 3); //just to have an image

        CvMat x = i.asCvMat(); //a CvMat of the image
        System.out.println(CV_IS_MAT(x)); //true, it's a mat

        matQ.position(0).put(x); //store it to array at position 0

        System.out.println(CV_IS_MAT(matQ.position(0))); //false!
        System.out.println(CV_IS_MAT(matQ)); //also false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Javacv(https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv) this is very easy task.

```
 String img ="Image.jpg";
 IplImage newImage0 = cvLoadImage(img);
 //import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_core.IplImage;
```

or

```
  Mat newImage1 = imread(img);
  //import org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_core.Mat;
  //import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_highgui.*;
```

If it is converted into CvMat type

```
CvMat imgcvMat0 = newImage0.asCvMat();
CvMat imgcvMat1 = new CvMat(newImage1);
//import org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_core.Mat;
```

same as you can convert it back to IplImage

```
imgcvMat0.asIplImage();
or 
imgcvMat0.asBuffer();
```

Comment: could not find any `asCvMat()` method in bytedeco javacv 1.4 or 1.1

Comment: Look at the documentation and if you come across update my answer as well which may helps to somebody like you

Comment: `asCvMat()` works for `IplImage` but does not work for `Mat` type. In case of `Mat mat_img` the following works for me `CvMat cvmat_img = new CvMat(mat_img)`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a cvMat, for example either if you read a path to image:

> String imgPath="./src/Imgs/chessboard.png"; 
>   Mat imgSrc = Highgui.imread(imgPath);

or if you create the cvMat element:

> Mat imgSrc2 =Mat.eye(3,3,CvType.CV_8UC1);

you can convert it to a java element IplImage,BufferedImage* :

```
BufferedImage img;
img = imgIO.Mat2BufferedImage(imgSrc);
```

To display the content of cvmat in the console  with:

> System.out.println( "cvMat element:\n" + imgSrc.dump() );

If you want to modify just a element into the matrix:

```
imgSrc.put(row, col, value);
imgSrc.put(2, 2, 1);
```

*The function Mat2BufferedImage:

```
// source: http://answers.opencv.org/question/10344/opencv-java-load-image-to-gui/

    /**
 * @param 
 * @return The output can be assigned either to BufferedImage or to Image
 */
public BufferedImage Mat2BufferedImage(Mat m){

    int type = BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY;
    if ( m.channels() > 1 ) {
        type = BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR;
    }
    int bufferSize = m.channels()*m.cols()*m.rows();
    byte [] b = new byte[bufferSize];
    m.get(0,0,b); // get all the pixels
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(m.cols(),m.rows(), type);
    final byte[] targetPixels = ((DataBufferByte) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
    System.arraycopy(b, 0, targetPixels, 0, b.length);  
    return image;

}
```